# How to traverse ForeignKeys in Django AdminSite?

Tags: django

How do I have the AdminSite show a list of all related_set objects pointing to a specific object.

The code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_contact = models.ForeignKey(User)


from django.contrib import admin
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```

I want the UserAdmin object view to show a list of all Contact objects that points to the specific User object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [InlineModelAdmin objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).